# Split text - get middle of a word only: js-(daniela)Cta

Tags: javascript

How to get only the middle of this id attribute:

js-danielaCta

I only want to get the word daniela but this word can be dynamic.
I basically want to remove the "js-" and "Cta" everytime.

How to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression, match everything in between in a group, and extract that matched group:

```js
const extract = id => id.match(/^js-(.+)Cta$/)[1]
console.log(extract('js-danielaCta'));
console.log(extract('js-abcCta'));
console.log(extract('js-foobarCta'));
```

Comment: Awesome! It works, is there a course/videos to learn about regular expressions?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html https://regexone.com/ https://www.rexegg.com/ I just googled [regex tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

This would work unless you will have js- or Cta inside the middle word.

```
var sample = "js-danielaCta";

var middle = sample.replace("js-","").replace("Cta","");
console.log(middle);
```

You may be better off using match with regex.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring, so if `var og =js-danielaCta`, then to get the middle, you do the indicies of the start and end letter, so `var new = og.substring(3, 9)`